# Why apply function is slowing down data.table R script performance (example provided)?

Tags: r, function, time-series, data.table, lapply

I am using stl time series to identify outliers from 150+ million rows grouped by different locations. It seems to be very slow because of usage of lapply+defined function as explained. I have also provided reproducible example to execute the script . Any suggestions to improve script performance or anything I am not doing right ?

### Sample Data.table

```
dt1=data.table(location_id=rep("abc",52),report_date=c(rep("2020-04-22",24),rep("2020-04-23",24),rep("2020-04-24",4)),hour=c(rep(c(0:23),2),0,1,2,3),hr_visitors=c(20:67,345,236,123,67))


dt2=dt1[, date_hour := as.POSIXct(paste0(report_date,hour), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")]
```

### This is the script that is taking more time

```
stl_model_outlier<-function(xyz){
model=ts(xyz,frequency=24)
f=stl(model,"periodic",robust = TRUE)
result=data.table(row_id=which(f$weights<1e-8))[,outlier:="Yes"]
return(list(result))
}

Sys.time()
"2020-09-30 06:41:51 GMT"

results1<-dt2[,lapply(.SD, stl_model_outlier), by = location_id, .SDcols = "hr_visitors"]

Sys.time()
"2020-09-30 06:54:51 GMT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
stl_model_outlier <- function(x) {
  x.ts <- ts(x, frequency = 24)
  weights <- stl(x.ts, "periodic", robust = TRUE)$weights
  fifelse(weights < 1e-8, "Yes", "No")
}

dt1[, outlier := stl_model_outlier(hr_visitors), by = location_id]
```

1. `fifelse` is a fast version of `ifelse`
2. Since you're applying to only one column, you don't need `lapply` and `.SD`.
3. You also don't need the line `dt2=dt1[, date_hour := ...`. data.table work by reference, check what happens to `dt1` after you run that line.

You also can pass everything direct to data.table instead of writing a function:

```
dt1[, outlier := fifelse(stl(ts(hr_visitors, frequency = 24), "periodic", robust = TRUE)$weights < 1e-8, "Yes", "No"), by = location_id]
```

Comment: I used all the suggestions , but it did not improve execution time much (only 10-15 seconds change)...it is almost taking similar time ....btw thanks for all suggestions